# My android phone is stuck whenever whatsapp pulls data/ What to do?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, samsung-galaxy-s-21

My android phone is stuck for about 30 minutes  whenever WhatsApp pulls data. My friend's phone is also stuck for 1-2 minutes on the same situation. It only happens when I have internet connection.  After a few minutes I get an error message telling me "system process is struck". WhatsApp continues to get messages on the background, but it is seemingly consumes all CPU resources.

Things I've checked:

1. My internet connection is working properly.
2. I've cleared the app cache.
3. This is a new samsung galaxy phone and the android version is updated. Whatsapp version is updated as well.
4. It also happens on my other phone.
5. There is plenty of storage.

Anyone experienced a similar phenomena? Any idea on what to do?